# Backbone.js render collection in View, but can't access data

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a Backbone Collection that represent a json objects and  I'm trying to render this objects in the View that would iterate them into template. I think the breakpoint was that i can't read the json array into array

The collection return array

```
{

    "calls": [
        {
            "callId": "173",
            "company": "Company 1",
            "status": "open",
            "DueDate": "2013-06-10 00:00:00",
            "EmployeeId": "12"
        },
        {
            "callId": "170",
            "company": "company 2",
            "status": "done",
            "DueDate": "2013-05-27 14:27:37",
            "EmployeeId": "11"
        },
        {
            "callId": "169",
            "company": "Company 3",
            "status": "open",
            "DueDate": "2013-05-20 00:00:00",
            "EmployeeId": "11"
        }
]

}
```

**Route**

```
// Filename: router.js
define([
    'jquery',    
    'underscore',
    'backbone',    
    'app/collections/schedule',
    'app/views/schedule',
    'app/views/dashboard'
], function($, _, Backbone, ScheduleCollection, ScheduleView, DashboardView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // Define some URL routes
            'dash': 'defaultRoute',
            'schedule': 'scheduleRoute',
            'accounts': 'accountsRoute',
            'reports': 'reportsRoute',
            // Default
            '*actions': 'defaultRoute'
        },
        scheduleRoute: function() {
            // Create a new instance of the collection
            // You need to set the url in the collection as well to hit the server
            var schedulecollection = new ScheduleCollection();
            // Pass in the collection as the view expects it            
            var scheduleview = new ScheduleView({
                collection: schedulecollection                        
            });            
           //scheduleview.initialize();
           // No need of calling render here
           // as the render is hooked up to the reset event on collection          
        },
        defaultRoute: function(actions) {            
            // We have no matching route, lets display the home page
            DashboardView.render();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {                
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

**Collection**

```
// Filename: collections/schedule
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'app/models/schedule'
], function ($, _, Backbone, ScheduleModel) {
    var ScheduleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ScheduleModel,
        url: "http://sam-client:8888/sam-client/i/schedule",
        initialize: function () {
            //console.log('schedule collections loaded successfully');
        }
    });
    return ScheduleCollection;
});
```

**View**

```
// Filename: views/schedule
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/schedule.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, ScheduleTemplate) {

    var scheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({        
        el: $("#test"),
        initialize: function () {
            // Listen to the reset event which would call render
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render());
            // Fetch the collection that will populate the collection
            // with the response 
            this.collection.fetch();                            
        },
        render: function () {   
            var data = {
              schedule: this.collection.models,
              _: _
            };
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(ScheduleTemplate, data);
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);                
        }
    });  
    return scheduleView;
});
```

**in The template**

```
<ul>
  <% _.each(schedule, function(call){ %>
   <li><%= call.get("company") %> - <%= call.get("DueDate") %></li> 
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

**The problem is there is no data passed in the template in order to iterate if it**

Comment: First change I would like to suggest is in, `views/schedule`, replace the line `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render());` with `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);`, reason is, to the `listenTo` we just need to pass a reference to `this.render` as a parameter, we don't need to call the method, so the time when `render` is called, there is no data present in order to generate the proper html from the template.

Comment: when changing it, the template can't be loaded .. i think that the render not called

Comment: When you remove `()` from `render`, is render being called on collection reset ?

Comment: no, so i had to add it

Comment: You know according to [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo), we can not call the method - render, we just need to pass the `callback` to the `listenTo`, and will be called automatically once the collection is fetched from the server.

Comment: you right, but still having the problem that i can't parse the json array into the template

Comment: (1) What version of Backbone are you using? (2) I don't see a [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method in your collection, you'd use that method to unwrap the incoming data so that the collection would just be working with an array of model data.

Comment: @muistooshort i'll upgrade to the latest version so i can ensure that all things working as expected, 2) where could i put parse method in the controller?

Comment: `fetch`'s reset behavior changed in Backbone 1.0 (check the ChangeLog), `parse` goes in the collection (check the docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse).

Comment: if you got the time, could you please update my collection with the new modifications. @muistooshort

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of [`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) changed in Backbone 1.0:

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> [...] When the model data returns from the server, it uses *set* to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass `{reset: true}`, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) *reset*.

So just this:

```
this.collection.fetch()
```

will trigger `'add'`, `'remove'`, and `'change'` events in Backbone 1.0+ rather than a single `'reset'` event like older versions of Backbone. If you say:

```
this.collection.fetch({ reset: true })
```

then you'll get your `'reset'` event.

The next problem is your JSON format. Backbone collections expect the incoming data to be a simple array of model attribute objects but your JSON has the array nested inside `"calls"`. You can provide a [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method in your collection to unwrap things:

```
parse: function(response) {
    return response.calls;
}
```

You'd want that method inside your `ScheduleCollection`.